# Is there a map $g$ from $S^1\times S^1$ to $S^2$ such that the induced map $g_*:H_2(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow H_2(S^2)$ is isomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$S^1\times S^1$ is not homeomorphic  to $S^2$.Can we construct a map $g$ from $S^1\times S^1$ to $S^2$ such that the induced map $g_*:H_2(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow H_2(S^2)$ is isomorphic.

Comment: Yes. You should try to do it.

Comment: Moreover it is true for any orientable surfaces

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can consider that $S^1\times S^1 =T^2$ is the quotient of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ by identifying $(0,t)\simeq (1,t)$ and $(t,0)\simeq (t,1)$. Then the map $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow S^2$ which identifies the boundary of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ to a point factors by a map $g:T^2\rightarrow S^2$ which sends the fundamental class of $T^2$ to the fundamental class of $S^2$.

Answer (score 0):

A surface in general has a description as a CW complex with one $2$-cell. If you look at $X/X_1$, i.e. the collapse of the one skeleton, you'll notice that you have a sphere. The map $X\rightarrow X/X_1$ induces an isomorphism on $H_2$.

Exercise: when do there exists maps $S^2\rightarrow \Sigma_g$ that induce isomorphisms on $H^2$?